# The nlocktime parameter in createrawtransaction seems not work using Bitcoin Core Wallet GUI

Tags: transactions, locktime, createrawtransaction

If I add the CLocktime (e.g 20) at the end it always gives:

```
Error: Error parsing JSON:{"12CxqQHzhFxCm2TkGkKHdFFPyUerFXcSte":0.008,"1DBDDvpcHv66LD7sWz1mCitPALW1qfrga7":0.012},
```

If I delete the CLocktime at the end it will be ok. 
Have anyone has similar experience and know why?

Comment: A nlocktime of 20 doesn’t make sense.

Comment: This is the format I used, but not work:                                                  createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]" "{\"address\":0.01, \"address\":0.01} 20"

Comment: 20 is still nonsense. It will always be valid because we are past block 20.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the locktime in the wrong place. You have

```
"[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]" "{\"address\":0.01, \"address\":0.01} 20"
```

but it should really be

```
"[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]" "{\"address\":0.01, \"address\":0.01}" 20
```

The locktime is a separate parameter, not part of the quoted parameter that has the transaction outputs. It goes outside of those quotes.